# Saving a bunch of meshs and using them to animate characters in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

I am trying to draw more than 2000 animated character on the screen at once, the problem is, skinning a mesh at runtime is too costly. So the solution I've found was to snapshot plenty of frames of animations then draw the appropriate mesh each frame for the characters to animate.

After some research, i've found a couple of possible solutions, but didn't succeed in using neither, they are:

- Using a Animation component, then selecting the animation/timeframe and calling 'animation.Sample()', then i can use SkinnedMeshRenderer.BakeMesh(myMesh). The problem is, when using Mechanim, you have a Animator component instead of a Animation, so far the only thing i am missing on using the Animator component instead of the Animation, is a equivalent to 'Sample()'. Without the 'Sample()' equivalent method, all i get is the mesh in T-pose each time i bake it.
- During the Update() method, setting the animation/timeframe in the animator, then waiting for the next frame to call 'SkinnedMeshRenderer.BakeMesh(myMesh)' works, sometimes. The biggest problem is having to wait a whole frame to be able to bake the mesh, not to mention it might stop working anytime now, since it's obviously not how it was meant to be done. I am not even sure if waiting for the next frame changes the position of the animation or not.

I would also accept any other solution, so long it uses Mechanim to do the animations

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on this subject but ...

Can you not do what the big boys do and "cheat" use instancing of the same mesh in its different states?

If there are 10 different "states" for that mesh you then basically have 10 different instanced draw calls to render a near limitless number of them from what i understand.

That way all the load is removed from the push between cpu and gpu and kept on the gpu when you have the power to handle such a large amount of data.

Comment: I am pretty sure that's the name of the thing i am trying to do... Though i am not sure. The current problem i have is to get those 'different states of the mesh'. I am a one-man team that only knows how to program, i am totally dependent Mechanim for animation, if i were to do those 'different states of the mesh' by hand it would take more than making the game, maybe